# RxJS: How to only start the next stream once the previous stream has completed

Tags: rxjs

I am batch loading data into a database and using RxJS to control the pipeline.

```
let event = 0;
parseStreamOfIndividualObjectsToInsert().pipe(
  bufferCount(100), // batch the inserts in groups of 100
  flatMap(batch => batchInsert(batch)
  // I want to go on only when all batch inserts are complete
  // performFurtherOperationOnlyOnce()
)
.subscribe(() => console.log('Hopefully will only log one event: ++event));
```

At the moment, the next method of the observer is firing after each batchInsert(), but I just want it to fire once, when all of the batch inserts have completed.

I have tried numerous combinations of concat and flatMap etc, but I still get multiple events emitted from the bulkInserts() flatMap line. Ideally, an event would only be emitted on completion.

Is it possible somehow only emit on completion?

Thanks

Comment: you may use [concat](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#concat)

Comment: Add a completion handler. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toArray` operation will do what you want. It'll `reduce` the entire stream into one event containing an array of everything:

```
const { bufferCount, flatMap, toArray } = require('rxjs/operators');

let event = 0;
parseStreamOfIndividualObjectsToInsert().pipe(
  bufferCount(100), // batch the inserts in groups of 100
  flatMap(batch => batchInsert(batch)
  toArray()
)
.subscribe(() => console.log('Hopefully will only log one event: ++event));
```

Comment: thanks very much. It works. I was thinking that I would have to trigger the start of the second observable stream from the complete function of subscribe's observable. I guess this makes sense, though just to emit a single array. I wish it was called something different, though, and I wish the docs actually had some content. </winge>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toArray` to reduce the stream of observables into a list.

You need to be sure that `parseStreamOfIndividualObjectsToInsert()` will eventually complete. I replaced `bufferCount` with `take` in order to force the stream to complete.

```
let event = 0;
parseStreamOfIndividualObjectsToInsert().pipe(
  take(100), // Force the stream to complete after 100 emissions
  // bufferCount(100), 
  flatMap(batch => batchInsert(batch),
  toArray()  # wait for Observable to complete 
)
.subscribe(() => console.log('Hopefully will only log one event: ++event));
```

Comment: thanks very much for your response. toArray was exactly what I needed.